# Vulkan Vulkan.hpp get opbject type from object instance

Tags: c++, graphics, enums, vulkan

Is there a way to get the object type enumerator (`vk::ObjectType` dor vulkan.hpp and `VkObjectType` for vulkan) from an instance?

E.g assume we have 3 objects:

```
vk::Device d;
vk::Buffer b;
vk::Queue q;
```

and a function f() such that:

```
f(d) returns: eDevice
f(b) returns: eBuffer
f(q) returns: eQueue
```

It doesn't matter whether this is in the lunar sdk, a third party library, or just a clever hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you could do that, then `VkDebugUtilsObjectNameInfoEXT` wouldn't need to take an `objectType`, would it ;)

So you have two choices, both of them requiring the same thing: a mapping table from the C/C++ object type to the actual `VkObjectType` enumerator.

There's the runtime choice, where you build a map of some kind which maps from a `std::type_index` to the `VkObjectType`. With `std::map`, you'd have this:

```
std::map<std::type_index, VkObjectType> objectMap = {
    {std::type_index(typeid(VkInstance)), VK_OBJECT_TYPE_INSTANCE},
    {std::type_index(typeid(VkPhysicalDevice)), VK_OBJECT_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE},
    {std::type_index(typeid(VkDevice)), VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE},
    ...
};

template<typename T>
void SetName(VkDevice *device, T *obj, const char *name)
{
    VkDebugUtilsObjectNameInfoEXT nameInfo =
    {
         VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEBUG_UTILS_OBJECT_NAME_INFO_EXT,
         nullptr,
         objectMap[typeid(T)],
         (reinterpret_cast<std::uint64_t>(obj),
         name,
    };

    vkSetDebugUtilsObjectNameEXT(device, &nameInfo);
}
```

A more compile-time solution can be had by using template specialization:

```
template<typename T>
struct VulkanObjectMap;

template struct VulkanObjectMap<VkInstance> { static VkObjectType value = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_INSTANCE; };
template struct VulkanObjectMap<VkPhysicalDevice> { static VkObjectType value = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE; };
template struct VulkanObjectMap<VkDevice> { static VkObjectType value = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; };
...

template<typename T>
void SetName(VkDevice *device, T *obj, const char *name)
{
    VkDebugUtilsObjectNameInfoEXT nameInfo =
    {
         VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEBUG_UTILS_OBJECT_NAME_INFO_EXT,
         nullptr,
         VulkanObjectMap<T>::value,
         reinterpret_cast<std::uint64_t>(obj),
         name,
    };

    vkSetDebugUtilsObjectNameEXT(device, &nameInfo);
}
```

You can use a macro to make defining the table nicer to look at.

Comment: Question, is there a way to do something similar to the cast interpretation for the vulkan.hpp objects?

i.e `reinterpret_cast<std::uint64_t>(obj)` where object is a vk::* object instead of a Vk* object?

Comment: @Makogan: I don't know; how do you get a real pointer to a real `Vk*` object from them? You'll have to use that API.